# Google Apps Script to get value match conditions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of data base in a google spreader (sheet "Data"). In column B it is a list of trucks, starting from B4:B3000. Column G is starting point (i.e G4 = "Start A or Start B" depending on which truck), Column H to Column AA are destinations for each truck which may have several stop (ie, "stop 1 at cell H4 and stop 2 at cell M4.

I have other sheet in the spread "List" with 2 cells for typing start and stop point (ie cell C1 for Start point, C2 for Stop point. When I type "Start A" in C1 and "Stop 1" in C2, them it makes a list of all trucks with value "Start A" in the column G and "Stop 2" in the column M (range H4:AA3000) in the "List" sheet.

Thanks to any one who can help me to create google apps script to get the results as expected.

Comment: Can any one help me? Thank you.

Comment: Try to reformulate. What did you have already done, what you want to do, why you don't achieve to do it. Also it dont seem that appscript is needed here, but you might get more help in the google-sheet tag